# Why is commitlog_total_space_in_mb disabled in the Cassandra 2.1.8 configuration

Tags: configuration, cassandra

My Commit log drive was filling up till i figured out that Commitlog_total_space_in_mb option in cassandra.yamnl is disabled. Can someone expalin why is it commented or disabled in 2.1.8.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the config file, the actual default value depends on whether you use a 32bit or 64bit jvm. It will be dynamically set after startup in case you don't specify a custom value.

Comment: where can we see the dynamically set value?